# Maintaining flexbox styling when using higher order components like react-reveal

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, higher-order-components

I am using `flexbox` with `styled-components` to layout and size the elements in my app. I want to add a reveal animation and am using the `react-reveal` module. According to the documentation it is supposed to work out of the box with styled-components.

**The problem is that the HOC wraps an extra div around the inner component which breaks the flexbox parent->child relationship.**

Here is how I add the animation.

```
const Card = styled.div`
   /* style */
   min-height: 400px;
   min-width: 100px;
   max-width: 400px;
   background-color: white;

   /* flex */
   display: flex;
   flex-basis: 25%;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: flex-start;
   align-items: center;
`;

/* apply fade in animation */
const Card = withReveal(card, <Fade bottom />)
```

This div is one of 3 divs inside a containing div that looks like

```
const InnerContainer = styled.div`
   width: 80%;
   max-width: 1200px;
   padding: 100px;

   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: space-evenly;
   align-items: center;
`
```

Without applying the animation this layout works correctly, but when I use the HOC `withReveal` it wraps another div around the Card Component which messes up the flex layout.

I've tried using other animation modules but this technique of using a HOC component is the one used by almost every reactjs animation or styling module.

I tried wrapping the HOC component in a `styled()` and adding `display: contents` to try and pass through the CSS to the children but this seems to mess up the layout even further.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own nested styles with `styled-components`

Try this

```
const InnerContainer = styled.div`
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 100px;

  > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
  }
`
```